# Call view from view SailsJS

Tags: html, node.js, view, sails.js, ejs

Okay, so I started working with SailsJS, based on NodeJS. The template engine I am using is EJS (all default).

I have not a single clue how to achieve the following:

**parent view called "main":**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="someDiv"><%- subviewContent %></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**subview:**

```
<% main(subviewContent = {
<p>I am inside someDiv of main parent view!</p>
}); %>
```

The controller should render "subview", subview calls main and at the end we have a full html page. It seems so logic and simple, but I can't find anything on this.
Does anyone have a suggestion, or should I switch template engine?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [layout templates](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views/Layouts.html) or [view partials](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views/Partials.html).

## Layout Template

If you want to have a [layout templates](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views/Layouts.html) (master page) that the same for every page with a body that's generated by a specific route:

> Sails layouts are special .ejs files in your app's views/ folder you
>   can use to "wrap" or "sandwich" other views. Layouts usually contain
>   the preamble (e.g. !DOCTYPE html....) and
>   conclusion (. Layouts are never used without a view- that would
>   be like serving someone a bread sandwich. Layout support for your app
>   can be configured or disabled in config/views.js, and can be
>   overridden for a particular route or action by setting a special local
>   called layout. By default, Sails will compile all views using the
>   layout located at views/layout.ejs.

## View Partial

If you want to reuse part of a view (a partial) across multiple views, like a sidebar or a contact us embedded form, you can do so with a [view partial](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Views/Partials.html).

Sails uses ejs-locals in its view rendering code, so in your views you can do:

```
<%- partial ('foo.ejs') %>
```

to render a partial located at /views/foo.ejs. All of your locals will be sent to the partial automatically.
the paths are relative to the view, that is loading the partial. So if you have a a user view at /views/users/view.ejs and want to load /views/partials/widget.ejs then you would use:

```
<%- partial ('../../partials/widget.ejs') %>
```

Comment: I am afraid that won't do it. Unless you can have a layout call another layout, it is not what I want. The View Partial is the other way around (you call the parent view, which will call the child view but I need to render the child view, which calls the parent view).

In short: Something like layout templates, but recursive (layout calls another layout, which can call another layout etc.).

Comment: Your question makes no mention of needing multiple parent layouts.. a layout with your master page html and a body that changes depending on the controller answers your stated requirements. If you're looking for something else I'd love to help, can you clarify what's missing?

Comment: Well, simply it is the other way around. Your way explains the following way:

Parent view » Child view » Child view » Child view

While I want the following way:

Child view » Child view » Parent view

Comment: Ahh I see, you want to define the name of the parent layout in the child view, is that correct?

Comment: I think you catch the drift. I want to return the child view from my controller, and the child view will call the parent view with some optional parameters.